# TypeError: Invalid argument type

Tags: reactjs, express, redis, axios, jwt

My express, react project TypeError is occurred. I want to store refresh token in redis and get it when i need.

```
C:\Users\lee\Desktop\shimterprj\backend\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\RESP2\encoder.js:20
[0]             throw new TypeError('Invalid argument type');
[0]                   ^
[0]
[0] TypeError: Invalid argument type
[0]     at encodeCommand (C:\Users\lee\Desktop\shimterprj\backend\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\RESP2\encoder.js:20:19)   
[0]     at RedisCommandsQueue.getCommandToSend (C:\Users\lee\Desktop\shimterprj\backend\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\commands-queue.js:187:45)
[0]     at Commander._RedisClient_tick (C:\Users\lee\Desktop\shimterprj\backend\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:429:76)
[0]     at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (C:\Users\lee\Desktop\shimterprj\backend\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:413:82)
[0]     at Commander.commandsExecutor (C:\Users\lee\Desktop\shimterprj\backend\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:167:154)
[0]     at BaseClass.<computed> [as set] (C:\Users\lee\Desktop\shimterprj\backend\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\commander.js:8:29)
[0]     at generateRefreshToken (file:///C:/Users/lee/Desktop/shimterprj/backend/passport/jwt-utils.js:31:15)
[0]     at file:///C:/Users/lee/Desktop/shimterprj/backend/routes/auth.js:63:30
[0]     at req.login.req.logIn (C:\Users\lee\Desktop\shimterprj\backend\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:44:13)
[0]     at file:///C:/Users/lee/Desktop/shimterprj/backend/routes/auth.js:55:11
```

I think redis is problem. Redis is used in generate and verify refresh token.

```
export const generateRefreshToken = (userId) => {
  const refreshToken = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "5m",
  });
  redisClient.set(userId, refreshToken);
  return refreshToken;
};

export const verifyRefreshToken = async (token) => {
  // const getAsync = promisify(redisClient.get).bind(redisClient);
  try {
    const { userId } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const data = await redisClient.get(userId);
    console.log(data);
    if (token === data) {
      return { userId, isReissue: true };
    } else {
      return { userId: null, isReissue: false };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
};
```

And axios response interceptor

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => {
    return res;
  },
  async (err) => {
    console.log("응답 인터셉트");
    if (err.response && err.response.status == 401) {
      const refreshToken = getCookie("refreshToken");
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/auth/reissue", {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${refreshToken}` },
          withCredentials: true,
        });
        const { newAccessToken, newRefreshToken } = data;
        setCookie("accessToken", newAccessToken, {
          expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 60000),
        });
        setCookie("refreshToken", newRefreshToken, {
          expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60000),
        });
        err.config.headers["authorization"] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
        return instance(err.config);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("토큰 갱신 실패");
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);
```

This is reissue router.

```
router.get("/reissue", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers["authorization"] ||
      !req.headers["authorization"].startsWith("Bearer")
    ) {
      return res.status(403).send("유효하지 않습니다");
    }
    const token = req.headers["authorization"].substring(7);
    const { userId, isReissue } = verifyRefreshToken(token);
    console.log(userId);
    console.log(isReissue);
    if (isReissue) {
      const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: userId } });
      const userWithoutPwd = user.dataValues;
      delete userWithoutPwd.password;
      const newAccessToken = generateAccessToken(userWithoutPwd);
      const newRefreshToken = generateRefreshToken(userId);
      return res.status(200).json({ newAccessToken, newRefreshToken });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

I don't know even what is problem. Why error occured. Please help me.

Comment: According to the error you posted, the specific file and line should be in `/backend/routes/auth.js:55:11`. Please direct us what is in that line so we can provide further help!

Comment: I found why error occured. When I set redis key I use integer like userId. And I set String(userId) for key, it solved